# how does synchronization work in this example?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system

I am trying to implement pipe system call as part of my semester project.

I came across the following code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/pipe.htm)

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pfd[2];
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;
    assert(argc == 2);

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1) { perror("pipe"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }


    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) { perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
        close(pfd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

        while (read(pfd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        close(pfd[0]);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
        close(pfd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
        write(pfd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(pfd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
        wait(NULL);             /* Wait for child */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Having studied Multiprocessor programming, I realize this is a producer consumer model. The main process is forking a child which is consuming the bytes written by the main process in the write end of the pipe.

I am not able to understand how the synchronization is working here. I mean how does the parent notify the child that it has written n number of bytes in the write end of the pipe?

Does closing unused fd's has anything to do with synchronization?

What if in this example, I want child to write something in the write end and parent to read it?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: The `read()` system call blocks until there is data to be read. So, your question is not clear. You must use `select()`/`pselect()` in order to tell whether there is data to read, which would mean that the parent did write to the pipe. I don't see any relation with syncronization here, I don't know operating system theory because I am not a computer scientist. Do you mean how the operating system manages this internally?

Comment: You need syncronization when you use threads, when you fork the virtual memory of the child is a *copy* of the parents. So you can access it randomly in both, and they become independent. A pipe, it's something different. And I don't think it would require syncronization from the OS. File descriptors are copied too, so you close the ones that you will not use indeed, like the read end of the pipe in the parent, you have to close it.

Comment: @iharob : thanks, you answered my question to an extent...though in `read()` system call's man pages i did not find that it is a blocking call..

Comment: It's because `read()` is not responsible for this behavior, it's a property of the file descriptor which you can alter BTW. Read [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/openat.2.html). By default they're always blocking unless you pass the `O_NONBLOCK` flag. Beware that non blocking IO could be challenging.

Comment: @pranav3688 Almost all system calls will block until they get what they need. When it comes to file descriptors every operation is blocking unless the file descriptor has been explicitly configured to be non-blocking. Blocking is the rule, not an exception, so there's no need to document it.

Comment: Read the [pipe(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).